# Async Adsense Ads works with Ajax, But is it against TOS

Tags: google-adsense, ajax

Google's Async adsense code loads fine even the page is loaded via ajax.

I made no changes to load the ads differently. Just added https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify on my site to make the content loading ajaxified.

My adsense loads fine also. Does it violate any TOS.

Answer (score 1):

It is against the Google AdSense policy to reload or refresh the ads when the user has not left the page.   If you ads are on a portion of the page that does not change when the user navigates with AJAX, you should be fine.

Google AdSense is not very compatible with AJAX.   They started a program to test AdSense with AJAX sites but have since shut it down.  The Google product help forums are full of complaints about Google Adsense not supporting AJAX.

Here is a decent post on StackOverflow about the issue: [Refresh a Div that has a Google ad inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it)